# Using multiple subdomains on Rails config.action_controller.asset_host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cdn, assets

I've setup a CDN using Cloudfront for my Rails 3 app. I created 4 CNAME redirects (cdn1.mywebsite.com, cdn2.mywebasite.com, etc) so I can parallelize the static assets download.

Is it possible to configure rails to use multiple assets hosts?

I tried

> config.action_controller.asset_host = ["http://cdn1.mywebasite.com", "http://cdn2.mywebasite.com", "http://cdn3.mywebasite.com", "http://cdn4.mywebasite.com"]

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html

> Browsers typically open at most two simultaneous connections to a
>   single host, which means your assets often have to wait for other
>   assets to finish downloading. You can alleviate this by using a %d
>   wildcard in the asset_host. For example, “assets%d.example.com”. If
>   that wildcard is present Rails distributes asset requests among the
>   corresponding four hosts “assets0.example.com”, …,
>   “assets3.example.com”. With this trick browsers will open eight
>   simultaneous connections rather than two.

You'd need to tweak your DNS a bit to start counting from 0 and then do:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://cdn%d.mywebasite.com'
```

Comment: Won't this affect caching? For example, if an application.css include renders with cdn1 domain, could it later render with cdn2 domain? or does Rails serve the same asset from the same host each time?

Comment: @eirikirSame host per asset. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-compute_asset_host and `host = host % (Zlib.crc32(source) % 4)`